# Why is the Still-Gennari reaction Z-selective?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Why is the Still-Gennari reaction *Z*-selective?
[image]

I guess dipole interactions have the biggest influence here. They somehow destabilize the reversion of the oxaposhpetane to the betaine and prevents formation of the more stable *E* isomer but I am not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you hopefully realise, the stereochemical outcome of the HWE reaction (and variations) is due to the relative orientation of the R-groups in the phosphaoxetane intermediate.

If the R groups are *syn* as in **5A** then the *(Z)*-olefin is formed, with an *anti* arrangement **5B** favouring the *(E)*-olefin as the product.

> [image]
>
> **Source:** *Modern Carbonyl Olefination*, Wiley, **2004**

The pertinent question when looking at the selectivity is why do we get dominant elimination from the *syn* phosphaoxetane (leading to the correct olefin), rather than dominant elimination from what is arguably the **sterically** most favourable *anti* phosphaoxetane (in which the R groups are pointing away from one another).

As it turns out, the initial 'aldol' addition into the aldehyde is rate determining, with the *anti* addition being favoured over the *syn* addition on steric grounds.

> [image]
>
> **Source:** *Stereoselective alkene synthesis*, Springer-Verlag, **2012**   (a really useful book, FYI)

Once the aldol addition has taken place, the subsequent steps are rapid due to the high electrophilicity of the Still-Gennari phosphonate (with the additional electron withdrawing groups).

This means that the entire process is essentially controlled by the initial addition to give a *syn* or an *anti* adduct. Once formed, the adducts are sufficiently short lived that despite the *cis* phosphaoxetane being less favoured due to the clash between R-groups, the *(Z)* olefin is formed *via* quick and irreversible elimination.

The HWE therefore is *(E)*-selective, in part, due to the fact that elimination is less rapid and as such there is equilibration to the more favourable phosphaoxetane from which elimination may occur.

Comment: Why is the (Z) olefin faster obtained?

Comment: The other thing I learnt is that, Still-Gennari conditions usually have something to sequester the metal ion - typically 18-crown-6 for K+. In a normal HWE the metal ion would stabilise the starting materials via chelation (as your diagram shows) and this would make the oxaphosphetane formation "more reversible" i.e. lower activation energy for reverse reaction.

Comment: The sequestering thing is pretty interesting. There are some really nice papers where they probe the effects of using various crown ethers etc.

Comment: In the first image you defined syn and anti as the relationship between the two R groups, in the second image it is between R and phosphonate group. Could you define in both cases syn and anti in the same way for clarity?

Comment: No.  This would be incorrect notation.  Though admittedly you would be understood

Answer (score 3):

I am not convinced by the transitions states given in "Stereoselective Alkene Synthesis" because they rely on chelation to restrict the conformation of the phosphonate anion AND the orientation of the aldehyde.

And yet, the reaction conditions are KHMDS/18-crown-6 which are clearly designed to eliminate the possibility of coordination to the potassium cation and maximise the rate of addition of the "naked" alkoxide anion to the electron deficient P.

My own suggestion for the intrinsic "anti" (in this example) selectivity of the fluorophosphonate anion is that it simply mirrors the intrinsic selectivity of the unstabilised Wittig ylid and Horner-Wittig (Ph2PO) stabilised anions both of which produce Z-alkenes stereoselectively.